# How to get node actions to display in IconView

Tags: netbeans, nodes, netbeans-platform

In my Netbeans Platform project I have a `TopComponent` with an `IconView` element, but when I add a `NodeAction` to the nodes it wont display. Right-clicking the nodes does not pop up a context menu. How do I get the action to display? This is what I have:

```
public class ItemDeleteAction extends NodeAction
{
    ⋮
    @Override
    protected boolean enable(Node[] nodes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            Node node = nodes[i];
            if (node instanceof ViewerItemNode) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    ⋮
}

public final class JFlavourViewerTopComponent extends TopComponent implements ExplorerManager.Provider
{
    public JFlavourViewerTopComponent()
    {
        ⋮
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new IconView(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
        actionMap.put("delete", new ItemDeleteAction());
        associateLookup(ExplorerUtils.createLookup(explorerManager, actionMap));
    }
}

public class ViewerItemNode extends AbstractNode
{
    private ViewerItem item;

    public ViewerItemNode(ViewerItem item, JFlavourProjectBean activeProject)
    {
        super (Children.LEAF, Lookups.singleton(item));
        this.item = item;
        setDisplayName (item.item.getLabel());
    }

    @Override
    public Action[] getActions(boolean context)
    {
        if (!context) {
            return new Action[]
            {
                SystemAction.get( ItemDeleteAction.class )
            };
        } else {
            return super.getActions(context);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Action getPreferredAction()
    {
        return SystemAction.get(PlayAudioAction.class);
    }
}
```

I think that's all the relevant code.

I do the same thing in another `TopComponent` in another module and it works fine, but in that module the nodes are displayed as a `BeanTreeView` instead of an `IconView`

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `context` condition:

```
@Override
public Action[] getActions(boolean context)
{
    return new Action[] {
        SystemAction.get(ItemDeleteAction.class)
    };
}
```